# Проблемы с правильным написанием скрипта в Unity C#. (Выстрел в игре в направлении крсора)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет. 
Прошу помочь разобраться с вопросом.
Я очень плохо разбираюсь в C#, Unity, да и попросту недавно начал обучение и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Мой скрипт как мне кажется должен делать следующее (Из моей позиции выпускать объект, который должен лететь в направлени[image: введите сюда описание изображения]и местоположения курсора)
Как мой скрипт на самом деле работает (Из моего положения летит объект в направлении координат 0. 0. 0.)
Вопрос: Как это исправить?

Скриншот скрипта прилагается.

Comment: А projectileForce равен 0?

Comment: Нет. Я его менял и ставил разные значения 0.5 , 1, 2. GameObject, назовём его условно fireball из любой точки где бы не находился персонаж стремиться в точку 0.0.0
Если нужны какие либо доп. скрины, информация и т.д. то с радостью предоставлю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы понять откуда у вас идут нули, ознакомтесь с значениями которые вы получаете.

```
Debug.Log("ProjectileForce:"+ProjectileForce);
Debug.Log("mousePos X:"+mousePos.x+" Y:"+mousePos.y);
Debug.Log("myPos X:"+myPos.x+" Y:"+myPos.y);
Debug.Log("direction X:"+direction.x+" Y:"+direction.y);
```

И наверняка вы сами поймёте как это исправить.
п.с. не публикуйте скрины кода, они не удобны, публикуйте текст кода.

---

ScreenToWorldPoint раньше не пользовался, попробывал, у меня всё работает, но интернет говорит что проблемы случаются. Похоже расстояние от камеры имеет значение, попробуйте так:

```
Vector3 mPos = Input.mousePosition;
mPos.z = 10;
mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mPos);
```

Comment: Куда бы не наводил мышь пишет, что "mousePos X:0 Y:0".
Тогда получается проблема в настройках камеры?

Comment: Скорее функции ScreenToWorldPoint. У вас 2d или 3d игра?

Comment: 2d игра (нужно больше символов)

Comment: `ScreenToWorldPoint` еще как **требует** правильной `Z` координаты. По факту, этот метод проецирует 2д точку в 3д пространство через какую-то плоскость, зависящую от камеры. Если `Z = 0`, то точка будет спроецирована на ближайшую к точке фокусировки камеры плоскость, а точнее это будет даже не плоскость, а эта же **точка** фокусировки камеры, а, как мы знаем, "точка" не имеет "размеров", оттого ЛЮБАЯ точка спроецированная на точку фокуса камеры будет иметь координаты `(0,0)`.

Comment: Ну и наугад выставленные значения Z координаты тоже ни к чему хорошему не приведут, для таких вещей лучше и надежнее использовать координату **near clip plane**'a - `camera.nearClipPlane`. Хотя в общем случае для 2D вообще лучше не использовать перспективные камеры, если не требуется полноценный 3д эффект графики. Однако в целом ответ хороший, +.